# SQL query to check if a column within a table has a specific value

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have a table that looks like this

```
A  | type_id | B
a  | 1       | b
a lot of more rows
...| ...     | ...
a2 | 3       | b2
```

What SQL query can I write to check if the type_id has the value 3? 
I can't just simply print out the table because the first 3 might be in 1 millionth row or somewhere I don't know.

What I have so far:

```
SELECT type_id FROM billing.activity ORDER BY type_id # what here?
```

Comment: what about a [where condition](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually need to add a `WHERE` clause in order not to worry about going through all of the data and only displaying the part that is relevant.

```
SELECT
    A
    , B
    , type_id
FROM billing.activity
WHERE type_id = 3
```

Also, the way you can think of this is not

"checking **IF** the type has the value 3"

but actually

"checking **WHAT** rows have the type equal to 3".

Hence, this is not really a check, but more of a filtering of data (displaying what you want to see based on the conditions you specify).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM billing.activity
 WHERE type_id = 3
 ORDER BY type_id ASC/DESC
```

For numeric Datatypes

```
SELECT * FROM billing.activity
 WHERE type_id = '3'
 ORDER BY type_id ASC/DESC
```

For Textlike Datatypes

Comment: If you specify `type_id = '3'` then `Postgresql` will convert it automatically to numeric when comparing. [**Example here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3b9f7e/1)

Comment: I really don't like to use implicit conversion, so i do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to just find the number 3 in the row use the following.

This will select the entire row from the table where type_id = 3

`SELECT * FROM billing.activity WHERE type_id ='3'`

Comment: missing `where` keyword  in code snippit  and were should be where in text...  Right Idea, take the time to help correctly!

Comment: OMG! such a newb mistake! Ironically I have been using sql stuff all day!

Corrected it now :D